# I want to Post my website url on my facebook friend wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website and on that one of my page I want a "Refer To Facebook Friend" button.., And by clicking on that I want list of all my Facebook friends list with a check box and a send button.., And by clicking on send button I want to post my Website URL to all my selected friends wall on Facebook..

I am new with Facebook API, And I do not have a game, I have a Website

thanks in advance

Comment: That is not possible. Use the Send dialog to send a Facebook message to a person or the Share dialog to share it to your own timeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

previously this was available via graph api , but they disabled it in their platform migration in [feb 2013](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/migrations/completed-changes#feb_2013) , cause of a lot of spam complaints. so you can't do it in php .

> **Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API** 
>   We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the `target_id` user is different from the session user, will fail. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). Stories that include friends via [user mentions tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/) or [action tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople/) will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag). For more info, see [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/).

but there is a work around for this allowing users to choose whom they want to post the content to. it is called [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2) . if you are using  javascript SDK feed . you can trigger it by,

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  caption: 'An example caption',
}, function(response){});
```

**note :**

> If a person has the "Who can post on your timeline?" setting set to "Only me" and another person tries to make a post using the Feed dialog, it will display a "Cannot post" error.